# meteor: recalculating helper value after typing some input values

Tags: javascript, meteor

My template looks like this:

```
<input type="text" name="inputValue" id="inputVal">

{{#each group}}
    <section>
        <h2>{{title}}</h2>
        {{#each element}}
            <p>{{description}} {{numberValue}} {{unit}}</p>
        {{/each}}
    </section>
{{/each}}
```

So far this is working. But now I want to do a little calculating by multiplicate the value of the inputfield with the numberValue (group.element.numberValue) and use this with `{{calculatedValue}}` in the template:

```
<p>{{description}} {{calculatedValue}} {{unit}}</p>
```

Therefore I need a helper:

```
Template.usedTemplate.helpers({
    'calculatedValue': function() {
        return document.getElementById("#inputVal").value * this.numberValue;
    }
});
```

I hope this is the correct coding for creating the helper as the values are used in an each-loop.

But my problem is, that the user types the inputValue after the site has been loaded. So what do I have to do, to recalculate the rows after the user typed some values in the input field?

(Also it would be great if there would be a kind of output info text at the beginning as there is no value given by default. After typing some value the result is been shown.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can simply use Session or ReactiveVar to solve your problem

```
Session.setDefault("input-value", "")

Template.usedTemplate.events({
  'keypress #inputVal': function (event) {
    Session.set("input-value", Template.instance().$("#inputVal").val());
  }
});

Template.usedTemplate.helpers({
  'calculatedValue': function() {
    return Session.get("input-value") * this.numberValue;
  }
});
```

or use ReactiveVar

```
Template.usedTemplate.onCreated(function(){
  this.inputValue = new ReactiveVar("")
})

Template.usedTemplate.events({
  'keypress #inputVal': function (event) {
    Template.instance().set(Template.instance().$("#inputVal").val());
  }
});

Template.usedTemplate.helpers({
  'calculatedValue': function() {
    return Template.instance().get() * this.numberValue;
  }
});
```

I suggest using ReactiveVar, because Session is global val.

And you should add ReactiveVar to your app before using.

```
meteor add reactive-var
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this code, but try this:

```
var userInput = new Tracker.Dependency;

Template.usedTemplate.events({
  'keypress #inputVal': function (event) {
    userInput.changed();
  }
});

Template.usedTemplate.helpers({
  'calculatedValue': function() {
    userInput.depend();
    return Template.instance().$("#inputVal").val() * this.numberValue;
  }
});
```

Side note: `document.getElementById()` already expects an ID as an argument, so you don't need the `#` prefix.

Normally, the `calculatedValue` helper will not update automatically because it contains no reactive method calls, such as `someCollection.find()` or `Session.get('xyz')`. But using `Tracker.Dependency`, you can make anything reactive.

Comment: I get the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: Tracker is not defined`

Comment: yes it is only in the client side... Is `Tracker`
 a own package?

Comment: Weird. That shouldn't happen at all. Can you dump your code to Meteorpad and comment here again once you've replicated it? I'd have to see it more context to figure out what's going on.